# Fade Out each div on click with the matching data attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

So lets say I have the following set up below.  3 of those articles have the same data-attr (this is coming from the database). I click remove I can easily fade out one. I do remove click > closest blah > fadeout

However I want to fade out not just that particular article on click, but any article that has that matching data attr.  Im not sure how to go about it.

Any tips would be appreaciated!

```
<article class="blah" data-attr="123">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="123">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="123">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="145">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="145">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="175">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
<article class="blah" data-attr="">
    //content stuff
    <a href="#" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
</article>
```

Comment: Could you add your Code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`attribute value`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
$('.blah .remove').on('click', function() {
    $('.blah[data-attr="' + $(this).closest('.blah').data('attr') + '"]').fadeOut();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zcL0ydh5/1/)

Comment: Explain a little bit more about the attribute value, and this would be a good because you've added a link already. But don't know why someone has given a DownVote

Comment: The button with the click event dosn't have the data-attr value, the parent article does.  You need to adjust the selector for the set that you fadeOut().

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.blah .remove').click(function () {
    var attr = $(this).parent().attr('data-attr');
    $(this).parent().siblings('[data-attr="'+attr+'"]').fadeOut();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut()
});
```

You can see it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/utxczuv0/1/

Comment: You could simply target the article elements with matching data-attr values instead of siblings and parents.

Comment: @SurrealDreams You could - guess it depends on the layout of the overall page, there's no enough info in the question to know one way or the other.  If there's two different areas on the page with individual articles, this will only remove them from the "current" one

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".blah").on('click', function() {
    $('article[data-attr="' + $(this).data('attr') + '"]').remove();
});
```